# How to remove elements from Struct

Tags: c, for-loop, struct

## I am wondering how the previously entered info can be deleted using decrement.

```
               case 4: printf("Remove Employee\n");
                    printf("===============\n");
                    do{
                        printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                        scanf("%d", &number);
                        int i;
                        for(i=0;i<NOE; i--){
                               if(number == emp[i].Int_Num){

                                  printf("Employee %d will be removed", emp[i].Int_Num);
                                   // for(i=0;i<NOE; i++){


                                  -- emp[i].Int_Num, --emp[i].Salary, --emp[i].Age;
                                 // scanf("%11lf", &emp[i].Salary);
                                  flag = 1;
                                  break;
```

Comment: you want to remove the employee struct from the array ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ..or just mark the entry as 'unused'?   You have not provided any system details or any data type info, just a bit of code and a requirement;(

Comment: This: 'for(i=0;i<NOE; i--){' looks disastrous.  Did you mean 'for(i=NOE-1;i; i--)' ?

Comment: In general, a flat list entry can be 'removed' by locating it, copying everything above it down one, (starting at the next entry up so as to copy non-destructively), and then decrementing the list count.

Comment: You can set the `Int_Num` to 0, or -1, to mark the entry unused.

Answer (score 0):

The typical data structure for a collection whose number of elements changes frequently, in arbitrary order, is a linked list. (Or, if you need faster access and have an order criteria like your employee number, a sorted tree). You would allocate new elements (here: employees) with `malloc()` and truly remove them from memory with `free`.

Alternatively, if there is a known maximum number of employees and you have enough memory you can use an array, which you appear to do here. The number of elements in the array would be the expected maximum number of employees; the program would therefore always need the maximum amount of memory, even with very few employees. On the other hand the memory footprint of the program would be statically known at compile time which can be an advantage.

The number of elements in an array cannot be changed (unless you allocate the whole array dynamically and reallocate if and when needed). Adding new employees or deleting existing ones would be done, as Bo Persson suggested, through a marker for those elements which are in use. That could be an extra boolean flag, or a special value in one of the existing fields.

In effect though you will be programming your own crude dynamic memory management that way, using the array as an "arena". It will probably be more buggy and slower than if you just used the built-in one.